# CKFinder Authentication issue with laravel 5 - error

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have see a good answer for my problem ([CKFinder Authentication issue with laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665618/ckfinder-authentication-issue-with-laravel-5)) but I get this error:

> Call to a member function `make()` on `bool`

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should provide more detail so we can reproduce your issue and help you out. If you need help in improving your question, take a look in [How to Crate a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hey @ajeferson thanks for your question! I will use the Laravel Auth. Auth::check, Auth::user()->id ... ... ... When I use the simple way from this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384565/11006259 I became the error what I write below.. :/